# split array based on delimiter

Tags: python

i have a numpy array like this:

```
 ['test_a','help_b','apple_c']
```

I want two arrays:

```
 ['test','help','apple']
```

and

```
 ['a','b','c']
```

Comment: you probably should just use lists

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you know how to iterate lists and split strings, you can put together a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure python solution:

```
x = np.array(['test_a','help_b','apple_c'])

a, b = zip(*[k.split('_') for k in x.tolist()])

>>> a # can always make this list(a)
('test', 'help', 'apple')
```

---

Using `pandas`

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(x).str.split('_').tolist())

    0       1
0   test    a
1   help    b
2   apple   c
```

such that

```
>>> df2[0].tolist()
['test', 'help', 'apple']
```

Answer (score 2):

If it would have been a list.  You can easily do it as under .

```
result1=[]
result2=[]
for item in input_list:
    r1, r2 = item.split('_')
    result1.append(r1)
    result2.append(r2)
```

Comment: You could also call `item.split('_')` once per iteration. :)

Answer (score 1):

Given a list:

```
In [11]: xs = ['test_a','help_b','apple_c']
```

I can split each element and then "unzip" (transpose) the results:

```
In [12]: a, b = zip(*map(lambda x: x.split('_'), xs))
```

This is what I'm left with:

```
In [13]: a
Out[13]: ('test', 'help', 'apple')

In [14]: b
Out[14]: ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension and tricky `numpy` rows unpacking:

```
a = np.array(['test_a','help_b','apple_c'])
x, y = np.array([x.split('_') for x in a]).T
```

Result:

x = `array(['test', 'help', 'apple'], dtype='<U5')`

y = `array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='<U5')`

Answer (score 1):

OR:

```
>>> l=your_numpy_array.tolist()
>>> a,b=[i.split('_')[0] for i in l],[i.split('_')[1] for i in l]
>>> a
['test', 'help', 'apple']
>>> b
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>>
```